# How to access form values with variable names?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have made a script that produces a form in a Google spreadsheet, takes its input values and appends them to the current sheet. All this works perfectly fine until I try and access the input values that have variable names.

I'm currently focusing on trying to get the inputs entered into the "Price" fields of which *i* are created with names *"vPrice" + (i + 1)* where *i* is the number entered previously in "Number of Variations" *numVar*.

In *varItemAdd()* I can access the values individually (*vPrice1, vPrice2* etc.) and they produce the correct values. I can also access the *numVar* value but when I try to incrementally adjust the *vPrice* variable to produce each value on the spreadsheet it comes up as '*undefined*'.

**Script:**

```
function varItemAdd(form) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

    var number = form.numVar;
    var attribNumber = form.numAttr;

    sheet.appendRow([form.manufacturer, number, attribNumber]);

    for (i=0;i<number;i++) {    
        var vPrice = "vPrice" + (i + 1);
        var vPriceInput = form.vPrice;
        sheet.appendRow([vPriceInput, number, attribNumber]);
        }
    return true;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <form>
        <!-- Select Number of Attributes to appear -->
        <h2 class="title">Number of Attributes:</h2>
        <input class="input-box" type="number" min="1" max="5" id="numAttr" name="numAttr" value="1"><br/>

        <!-- Select Number of Variations to appear -->
        <h2 class="title">Number of Variations:</h2>
        <input class="input-box" type="number" id="numVar" name="numVar" value="1"><br/>

        <h3 class="buttons" id="submit" onclick="addFields()">ADD</h3>
        <div id="attBoxes"></div>
        <div id="varBoxes"></div>
        <br>
        <input class="buttons" id="submit" type="button" value="SUBMIT"
    onclick="google.script.run
        //.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)
        .varItemAdd(this.parentNode)" />
        <input class="buttons" id="reset" type="reset" value="RESET">

    </form>
</body>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    function addFields(){
        // Get number of variation inputs to create
        var number = document.getElementById("numVar").value;

        // Get number of attribute inputs to create
        var attribNumber = document.getElementById("numAttr").value;

        // Get container <div>s where dynamic content will be placed
        var varBoxes = document.getElementById("varBoxes");
        var attBoxes = document.getElementById("attBoxes");

        // Clear previous contents of the container
         while (varBoxes.hasChildNodes()) {
            varBoxes.removeChild(varBoxes.lastChild);
        }
        while (attBoxes.hasChildNodes()) {
            attBoxes.removeChild(attBoxes.lastChild);
        }
        attBoxes.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Attribute Name(s)"));

        // For each attribute append an input box inside each variation
        for (k=0;k<attribNumber;k++){              
            var attTitle = attBoxes.appendChild(document.createElement("h2"));
            var attInput = attBoxes.appendChild(document.createElement("input")); 

            attTitle.textContent = "Attribute " + (k + 1);

            attInput.type = "text";
            attInput.name = "v-att" + (k + 1); 
            attBoxes.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

            };
        attBoxes.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

        // For each variation create inputs
        for (i=0;i<number;i++){
            varBoxes.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Variation " + (i+1)));

            // Set variables
            var skuTitle = varBoxes.appendChild(document.createElement("h2"));
            var skuInput = document.createElement("input"); 
            var priceTitle = varBoxes.appendChild(document.createElement("h2"));
            var priceInput = document.createElement("input");
            var attributes = varBoxes.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
            attributes.id = "varAttribs";
            var varAttribs = document.getElementById("varAttribs");

            // Set element values
            skuTitle.textContent = "SKU";

            skuInput.type = "text";
            skuInput.name = "vSku"; 

            priceTitle.textContent = "Price";

            priceInput.type = "number";
            priceInput.id = "vPrice" + (i + 1);
            priceInput.name = "vPrice" + (i + 1);


            // Call elements
            varBoxes.appendChild(skuTitle);
            varBoxes.appendChild(skuInput);
            varBoxes.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            varBoxes.appendChild(priceTitle);
            varBoxes.appendChild(priceInput);
            varBoxes.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

            for (j=0;j<attribNumber;j++){
                var aValueTitle = varAttribs.appendChild(document.createElement("h2"));
                var aValueInput = document.createElement("input");

                aValueTitle.textContent = "Attribute " + (j + 1) + " Value";
                aValueTitle.className = "title";

                aValueInput.type = "text";
                aValueInput.className = "input-box";
                aValueInput.name = "a-value-" + (j + 1);

                varBoxes.appendChild(aValueTitle);
                varBoxes.appendChild(aValueInput);
                varBoxes.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
                };


            varBoxes.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            varBoxes.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        }

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the below line in script then you should be able to access the value of each price element.

**From**:

```
var vPriceInput = form.vPrice;
```

**To**:

```
var vPriceInput = form[vPrice];
```

Comment: That's perfect thank you! Didn't realise you couldn't use dot operators on variables.